# How to add a fadeIn effect revealing a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the help of other members I have the following code that allows to show and hide divs one at a time.

If I click on a button it will show the corresponding div and if I click on another button, the previous div goes away and the next will show.

However, when I click on a button to show a div, it does not have any transition or timing effect. It shows up immediately

If in the function I add a timing like this.. `$(id).show(800);` It will have the transition or fadeIn effect, but if someone click on a button to show the div and click on the same button again to hide it, the div will go away and return right back.

Can someone help me to add that transition or fadeIn on a way that if the button is clicked to hide the div it will stay hidden?

This is what I have:

```
<p class="btn" onclick="toggleDivs('#div1');">Show div1</p>
<p class="btn" onclick="toggleDivs('#div2');">Show div2</p>
<p class="btn" onclick="toggleDivs('#div3');">Show div3</p>
<p class="btn" onclick="toggleDivs('#div4');">Show div4</p>
<div class="fadeOut" id="div1" style="display:none"; >

    <div class="fadeOut" id="div1" style="display:none"; >
<div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div1</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="fadeOut" id="div2" style="display:none"; >
<div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div2</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="fadeOut" id="div3" style="display:none"; >
<div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div3</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="fadeOut" id="div4" style="display:none"; >
<div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div4</p>
</div>
```

```
var toggleDivs = function (id) {
$(".fadeOut").hide(800);
$(id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should disable all buttons untill the end of the animation:

```
var toggleDivs = function (id) {
    $('.btn').attr('disabled', true)
    $(".fadeOut").hide(800, function() {
        $(id).show(800, function() {
            $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });
}
```

I suggest you add another class to your buttons that are going to be disabled in order to not disable all buttons with class `btn` in the DOM.